# Chef insufficient Permissions error on file resource

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I have a file, let say xyz.sh, mounted from different file system on centos and root user does not have access to change the permissions of the file.
Current permissions are 755 for the file. 
My cookbook's file resource checks for the permissions and if it is not 755 then change it to 755. 
When I run the cookbook as root user it is giving an exception as 'Insufficient Permissions'. 
Now I would have expected this exception if the file had some different permissions and chef tried to change it but not able to do that, but here as permissions are same as expectation, then why am I getting this exception? 
Please help me!

Comment: Show your recipe code, I assume your desired mode and actual mode are not exactly the same. Moreover you say mounted from a different file system, what is the source filesystem ? What does `stat  <file.sh>` return exactly ? When mounting a remote file system, the remote server may deny listing the permissions or return a vanilla access.

Answer (score 0):

Root is supposed to have permission to access any file in most cases (give or take some retrofits of the Unix filesystem model like POSIX ACLs). Regardless, just remove the `mode` property from the resource and Chef won't try to enforce anything.

Comment: But I can't remove mode property, as the resource iterate over multiple files and changes permission if any deviation found. But the problem is that for one file root can't change permission. My question that, should not chef have skipped the file as permissions are same?

Comment: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/file_access_control/unix.rb#L187-L215 is the relevant code, it it's an exact match it shouldn't try to `chmod` but since you're already in a very weird situation with root not having access I wouldn't be surprised if there is something else going on.